# How to mitigate "," char breaking Unity connection to SQLite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have a small [Unity application](https://www.moddb.com/mods/might-magic-heroes-55/downloads/mmh55-reference-manual-rc15-beta-2) that holds the data in a SQLite database.
Application works when installed with the exception it does not when the path contains "," sign.

For example:

- Working install dir: C:\games\heroes55\manual\MMH55 RC15B2.exe
- Faulty install dir: C:\games\heroes5,5\manual\MMH55 RC15B2.exe
- this one also works properly: C:\games\heroes5.5\manual\MMH55 RC15B2.exe

The error reported is **"Argument Exception: Invalid connectionString format for parameter"**
[image: DB connection error]

This is the way the DB connection is defiled in Unity:

```
string conn = "Data source=" + Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Database/skillwheelRC15B1.db";
```

I have never seen this issue nor i have idea how to start troubleshooting it. Could you advise how definition of the path can be changed to mitigate that issue?

Comment: Does the same happen if instead of `Data source` you use `"URI=file:" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Database/skillwheelRC15B1.db";` ?

Comment: Hey, I changed it to the value but the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for what arguably are breaking characters. Commas. Semi colons. Quote marks. In your case caused by locale of a float number. To the English world 5.5. To some countries 5,5.  Im sure there are other breaking characters it will be documented. Its not clear from your code if you are using odbc or a direct sql or what but each will have documented a list of special characters

Comment: Thank you!

 `string conn = "Data source=" + Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Database/skillwheelRC15B1.db";
dbconn = new SqliteConnection(conn);
dbconn.Open();`

I will check documentation for SQL :)